# MySQL Connector/NET Any() inside Where() causes NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework, connector-net

I have a query that is dynamically generated for the purpose of searching a rather large set of records. I am using MySQL Connector/NET 6.8.3 via a NuGet package with Entity Framework 6. The `Expression` which is executed inside the `Where` is built programmatically.

For an explanation of the problem I am seeing, I have a record which has many detail records. My filter generates the following expression (this is the output from `Expression.ToString()`):

```
Expression<Func<DB.record, bool>> filter = t => t.details
    .Where(d => (d.value== value(Filters.ContainsValueFilter).Value))
    .Any()
```

So, the query is first executed like so to get me a record count (for my pagination):

```
context.records.Where(filter).Count();
```

This works just fine. However, when I do the next query things fall apart:

```
context.records.Where(filter)
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.transaction_time)
    .Skip(page * pageSize) //page and pageSize are ints
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToList();
```

This query throws a `NotImplementedException` (inside a `System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandCompilationException`) which occurs here:

```
at MySql.Data.Entity.SelectStatement.Accept(SqlFragmentVisitor visitor)
at MySql.Data.Entity.ExistsFragment.Accept(SqlFragmentVisitor visitor)
at MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.VisitAndReplaceTableName(SqlFragment sf, String oldTable, String newTable)
at MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.FuseSelectWithInnerSelect(SelectStatement outer, SelectStatement inner)
at MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.TryFusingSelect(InputFragment f)
at MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.VisitInputExpression(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type)
at MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.VisitInputExpressionEnsureSelect(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type)
at MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbLimitExpression expression)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbLimitExpression.Accept[TResultType](DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor)
at MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.VisitInputExpression(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type)
at MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.VisitInputExpressionEnsureSelect(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type)
at MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbProjectExpression expression)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbProjectExpression.Accept[TResultType](DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor)
at MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.GenerateSQL(DbCommandTree tree)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, BridgeDataReaderFactory bridgeDataReaderFactory, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)
```

**My Question:**

What causes this? I have a copy of the MySQL Connector/NET source code that I have been looking at and I see this:

```
internal override void Accept(SqlFragmentVisitor visitor)
{
  throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}
```

What am I doing wrong to even call this method? Why can't it handle a query with an `Any` inside a `Where` that then does `OrderByDescending`, `Skip`, and `Take`? That seems like a perfectly reasonable query to me (and I could write out the SQL easily...its an `ORDER BY` followed by a `LIMIT X,Y` after a `WHERE` which contains an `EXISTS`).

This has happened to me quite a bit and while I have generally found ways to get around this (and will probably end up doing the same here again), I am just getting frustrated always running in to this when I need to executed a simple query (generally involving an `Any` inside a `Where`).

Comment: Please, file a bug at their website: http://bugs.mysql.com/ At least they know about it and maybe fix it. I'm using Connector .NET and I'm finding some too.